# Remove text highlighted rounded corner in Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, editor, sublimetext

I don't like the rounded corner on the highlighted text in sublime text 3. How can I disable this feature from the sublime text?

[image: e]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rounded corners of selected text in Sublime Text is controlled by the `selection_corner_style` global setting of your **active color scheme**. In order to change it, there are basically two ways. You can follow any one.

1. If you have the `PackageDev` package installed, then you can choose `PackageDev: Edit Current Color Scheme` from the command palette. This will open a split window layout with the default color scheme on your right group & your User version on the left group. Add `selection_corner_style: "square"` to the existing `global` values and save the file. This will get rid of the rounded corners and give it sharp corners instead.
2. The second (and the laborious way if you don't want to install a package) is to follow these steps :-

- Find out your active color scheme name from the `color_scheme` setting from your User preferences (go to `Preferences: Settings` from the command palette).
- Create a file by that exact same name in the `User` directory (`Preferences -> Browse Packages ...` from the main menu).
- Paste the following

```json
{
    "variables": {
        // Define variables here
    },
    "globals": {
        "selection_corner_style": "square",
    },
    "rules": [
        
    ]
}
```

- Save the file.

Note: If you are using a custom color scheme and don't define the `selection_corner_style`, the default value of this key is `round` & it will still apply.

Comment: I do like to follow the 2nd method. Should my file name Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Mariana.sublime-color-scheme OR Default/Mariana.sublime-color-scheme? plz https://imgur.com/Riduqt6

Comment: It should just be Mariana.sublime-color-scheme saved in your User directory.